# Visual Studio ignoring include directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am running Visual Studio Community 2017 and Windows 10.  I have a project for which I have added an include-file directory under Project > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories, but Visual Studio simply ignores the directory and will not find the include files.  It finds the files if I hard-code the directory into the #include statement.  I checked the .vcxproj file and the directory shows up there.  I just updated/corrected Visual Studio to the most recent version and have since re-booted, but the problem remains.  Help, please!

Comment: This is most certainly a problem with the way you've set something up. Are you sure you're compiling in the correct configuration that you've changed?

Comment: I'm back to C++ programming with VS after about 10 years or more just to realize that this problem still exists!? Yes, same here: The path is configured correctly in x64. I even tried to copy it from win32 (where it works), but VS claims it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Additional ideas for troubleshooting this kind of issue:

When using vs2015 you can try to add '#include <*somenoneexistingfile.h*>' to the top of any .c/.cpp and right-click on it to open a context menu and select "Open Document <*somenoneexistingfile.h*>. This will open a dialog showing you the actual paths being used for including. Note: This specific approach doesn't work with vs2019 or later.

Besides this, you can check if:

1. you edited the actual configuration (Debug/Release) which you are starting, i.e. maybe you only edited the additional-include-path for the debug-build but are trying to compile a release-build.
2. you edited the actual platform (x64 vs x86) which you are starting, i.e. maybe you only configured the additional-include-path for x86 but are trying to compile the x64 platform.

Comment: In what version of Visual Studio does it show the actual paths. In Visual Studio 2022 the useless message is
[Microsoft Visual Studio]
File 'notme' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths.
[  OK   ]

Comment: Tried it with vs2019 and indeed it doesn't work anymore. At the time of writing I think I tried with vs2015, will update to reflect that change.

Comment: I had the exact problem and your second bullet resolved things for me. My configuration was configured under x64 but I was building x86. It drove me crazy and I didn't realize why no header files were found. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that MFC is enabled in project properties > Configuration Properties > General
use of mfc must be set to static or dynamic library.
then to ensure that cl.exe is using all of the include directories that you specify, you need to go to project properties > c/c++ > general and change suppress startup banner to no /nologo.this will give you the full cl command for each source file, showing exactly what visual studio is attempting to do with the code and configuration options that you give to it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  The project I am working on is a simple console application (.exe) that has worked for years and is simply in need of a small tweak.  It does not use MFC and /nologo has been set.  I tried creating a brand new project instead of using the one ported from Visual Studio 2015 (which worked fine, but I've deleted VS2015).  It turns out that I have the same problem--directories being ignored--when specifying a path to a function library.

Comment: As a further update, I created a default console application and then changed Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories to include "H:\Test" ahead of $(IncludePath).  I made no other changes.  If I   #include "H:\Test\myheader.h" it works; #include "myheader.h" does not.  It would be a simple fix except that there are many linked headers.